# Inconsistency between GPIO block diagram and interrupt table in the BCM2835 datasheet

Tags: gpio, interrupts

I'm looking at the BCM2835 datasheet https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf. On page 89, there is a block diagram for the GPIO module, as attached below. It is clear that there are **three** interrupt lines going out of the module.

[image: GPIO Block Diagram]

However, the interrupt table, specified on page 113, shows there are **four** GPIO interrupt lines going into the interrupt controller.

[image: Part of the Interrupt Table]

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here? Why is there an extra input on the IC? Any hint or pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BCM2835 datasheet that you referenced was written for the first generation Raspberry Pi, in which there were only 2 banks of GPIO pins.

On the BCM2837 (the SoC used in the Raspberry Pi 3), there are actually 3 banks of GPIO pins, so there are four interrupt lines going from the GPIO controller to the interrupt controller.

- gpio_int[0] for BANK0 (pins 0-27)
- gpio_int[1] for BANK1 (pins 28-45)
- gpio_int[2] for BANK2 (pins 46-53)
- gpio_int[3] for all the pins

You can verify this with the "raspi-gpio get" command, which lists each pin's function (INPUT/OUTPUT/ALT). If you filter the results with grep, you should see:

```
raspi-gpio get | grep BANK

BANK0 (GPIO 0 to 27):
BANK1 (GPIO 28 to 45):
BANK2 (GPIO 46 to 53):
```

Even though the GPIO controller in the original BCM2835 only had 2 banks, Broadcom was forward–looking and reserved a bit in each register of the interrupt controller for future versions, the gpio controller of which would have an additional bank.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph introducing that table (pg. 112) reads:

> The following is a table which lists all interrupts which *can* come from the peripherals which *can* be handled by the ARM.

The diagram on page 89 and the description which follow do make it explicit only three interrupt lines are *used*.

This does not seem like any kind of contradiction or inconsistency to me, anymore than having 4 phone jacks in my apartment but only 3 phones would be considered inconsistent.  Having 5 phones might be a problem.